# 'lines' and 'lines+markers' mode is not working in plotly python

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, plotly

I am trying to plot a time series plot with plotly's 'lines+markers' mode
although I was successful in plotting both lines and markers with some columns , I am unsuccessful for few columns and on those few columns only 'markers' mode works, but the data type of all these columns are float64.

Below is the snippet of code being used

```
trace = go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['some_column'], mode='lines+markers', name='some_column',line=dict(width=0.5,color='red'),marker=dict(size=2, opacity=0.5),showlegend=False) 
fig = py.tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1) 
fig.append_trace(trace, 1, 1) fig['layout'].update(title = 'some title' ) ;
py.offline.plot(fig, filename=strFilename + str(v) + '.html')
```

I found that there are missing values in those columns in which 'lines+markers' is not working 
Any solution on how to tackle the missing data?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer from https://community.plot.ly/t/missing-line-in-mode-lines/11429/4 
Apparently due to the missing gaps I have to use `connectgaps=True`

So the code should be like

```
trace = go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['some_column'], mode='lines+markers', connectgaps= True,name='some_column',line=dict(width=0.5,color='red'),marker=dict(size=2, opacity=0.5),showlegend=False) 
fig = py.tools.make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1) 
fig.append_trace(trace, 1, 1) fig['layout'].update(title = 'some title' ) ;
py.offline.plot(fig, filename=strFilename + str(v) + '.html')
```

Thanks for your interest